# solving ode with sqrt yields warning

Tags: python, numpy, ode, sqrt

I am trying to solve an ode equation with a boundary condition. The issue is that I have a squareroot that yields the warning "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt".

```
def F(x,y):
    F = np.zeros(1)
    F[0] =1/(2*(1-c**2)*y[0])*(-1+c*np.sqrt(1-(c**2*(1-c**2) *(y[0])**4)/(x**2)))
    return F
```

My guess is that the sqrt assumes that y[0]^4 is some value such that the value inside the squareroot is negative, but I am not sure how to fix it if that is the case

Comment: Calculate the argument to `sqrt` first and put it in a variable. Check whether it's negative.

Comment: It's not **assuming** anything. If the argument is negative, it's invalid.

Comment: The thing is that I am trying to determine y[0], so whether or not it will be negative depends on whatever value y[0] is. So one of the restrictions as to what y[0] can be is that it must be a value such that the argument is not negative.

Comment: @zalba19 python cannot assume. there is a specific value that is passed to it and tries to calculate based on that. add a print before the F[0] to see for yourself.

Comment: @zalba19 Your choice of variable names is also bad. x is scalar but y is an array while they seem to be of the same type, the function and the returned value has the same name; the very creative 'F' and finally, since F only has a single value why is it initialized as an array of zeros of lenght 1? Why are you complicating your life?

Comment: y[0] ^ 4 has to be a positive number unless y[0] is a complex number.  If you have a negative number, it must come from one of the addition terms in the equation, e.g. c ** 2 > 1.  Also, why are you defining F = np.zeros(1)?